# Trying to delete the records if greater then 25?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete all records so I only have the last 25 records. I am trying to figure this out but I can't seem to figure out, my MySQL version doesn't support the `DELETE LIMIT OFFSET` that most suggest, so I am trying to do

```
DELETE FROM
    account_versions
WHERE
    account_versions_id < (
        SELECT
            account_versions_id
        FROM
            account_versions
        ORDER BY
            account_versions_id
        DESC
        LIMIT 24, 1)
 AND
     account_id = 1
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. I want to only have the last 25 records for `account_id = 1`

Comment: the `account_versions_id` is an autoincrement?

Comment: Yes it is primary and auto increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you said that `account_versions_id` is an autoincrement. Here is what you need:

```
DELETE FROM account_versions
 WHERE account_id = 1 
   and account_versions_id IN
      (select account_versions_id 
         from 
         (SELECT account_versions_id, @id:=@id+1 as rn
            FROM account_versions,
                 ( select @id:=0 ) a
           ORDER BY account_versions_id DESC) x
        where rn > 25)
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Is there anyways to not use a LIMIT in subquery I get `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: Didn't see the `account_id = 1` part of the problem. I've fixed it.